# Can I deploy into virtual directory?

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.2, iis-and-asp.net

I have deployed the DXA in IIS. I have a website configured as like this IIS--MyDomain--MySite-1.
So, say for eg: https://jey.com/mystagingsite is the site developed and deployed by DXA.

Now, I have configured the `cd_dynamic` and `cd_link` config file as below.

```
 <Host Domain="jey.com/mystagingsite/" Port="443" Protocol="https" Path="/" />
```

When I hit the version.json, am getting error as below

```
No matching Localization found for URL 'https://jey.com/mystagingsite/version.json'
```

"MyStagingSite" is the virtual directory and converted as a application too with 443 port.

If i publish and point the DXA to "https://jey.com" it works fine. So, how to point the site to the virtual directory?

Update:
Please note that adding the staging and active website needs to be served from the same URL but with different context like https://jey.com/mystagingwebsite and https://jey.com/mywebsite. So adding the publication path and adding path to DXA configuration may not work in our scenario.

We also noticed the the application is trying to resolve to `jey.com/mystagingwebsite:443` during resolution. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Be sure the Publication ID matches, the `Domain` attribute doesn't have a path, and the `Path` has the correct path ("/mysite" in this case). Alternatively you could try changing the Publication path in the Publication properties, but it's probably best to leave that alone for future upgrades.

Comment: Hi Reyes - Please check the updated question. Publication ID is perfect. Because of my existing IIS site setup, i need to add the Virtual Directory name in the domain. Also i need to add some extra in the publication property. But if i add the virtual directory in the domain, DXA excluding the virutal directory in the URL domain property. So, am getting the No matching URL found exception.

Comment: As far as I know, domains do not have paths. Try instead: `<Host Domain="jey.com" Port="443" Protocol="https" Path="/mystagingsite" />`. Otherwise also add the version of Tridion you're working with for help from others.

Comment: am using Tridion 2013 SP1. If i add "mystagingsite" in path. DXA looking file  path in Broke DB as /mystagingsite/version.json. But in DB, it is actually it will be /version.json.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is not possible in 2013 SP1 in general; it is only possible with SDL Web 8 Topology Manager (using so-called context-relative URLs in CM).